# How to convert a column of ints, NaN, and strings to only integers and NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['John','Mary', 'Phil', 'Sue', 'Robert', 'Lucy', 'Blake'],
    'age': ['15', '20s', 37, 'teen', '', 'elderly', 57]
    })

df


    name     age
0   John     15          
1   Mary     20s
2   Phil     37
3   Sue      teen
4   Robert  
5   Lucy     elderly
6   Blake    57
```

I would like to:

1. convert the `age` column into integers (where there is an integer already, or where one is able to be deduced, e.g. from a string)
2. otherwise replace with `NaN`

Here is what I'm looking to get:

```
name         age
0   John     15            <--- was originally a string
1   Mary     NaN
2   Phil     37
3   Sue      NaN
4   Robert   NaN
5   Lucy     NaN
6   Blake    57
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following, using the `apply` method.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['John','Mary', 'Phil', 'Sue', 'Robert', 'Lucy', 'Blake'],
    'age': ['15', '20s', 37, 'teen', '', 'elderly', 57]
    })

def func(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except:
        return np.NA

df['age'] = df['age'].apply(func)
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a `pd.to_numeric` then convert with `'Int64'` , usually NaN and int could not be mixed.

```
df['new'] = pd.to_numeric(df['age'],errors = 'coerce').astype('Int64')
df
Out[26]: 
     name      age   new
0    John       15    15
1    Mary      20s  <NA>
2    Phil       37    37
3     Sue     teen  <NA>
4  Robert           <NA>
5    Lucy  elderly  <NA>
6   Blake       57    57
```